# Target does not exist Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Recibo el siguiente error :

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers\AuthController] does not exist.

Archivo web.php

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/




Route::get('dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'dashboard']); 
Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('custom-login', [AuthController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom'); 
Route::get('registration', [AuthController::class, 'registration'])->name('register-user');
Route::post('custom-registration', [AuthController::class, 'customRegistration'])->name('register.custom'); 
Route::get('signout', [AuthController::class, 'signOut'])->name('signout');
```

AuthController:

```
<?php

//namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;
use Session;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }  
      

    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                        ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }



    public function registration()
    {
        return view('auth.registration');
    }
      

    public function customRegistration(Request $request)
    {  
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
           
        $data = $request->all();
        $check = $this->create($data);
         
        return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('You have signed-in');
    }


    public function create(array $data)
    {
      return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
      ]);
    }    
    

    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return view('dashboard');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('You are not allowed to access');
    }
    

    public function signOut() {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
  
        return Redirect('login');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Editado:

Se agrego namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers; al controlador y  al llamar cualquiera de las rutas se recibe este error:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [AuthController] does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

El problema de ubicación de tu clase *`AuthController`* parte del *namespace* en el cual la declaras y posterior con el que tratas de invocarla, pues si notas:

- Haces la importación de este modo:

  ```
  use App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers\AuthController;
  ```
- Pero declaras a dicha clase bajo el contexto del siguiente *namespace*

  ```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  ```

Dado lo anterior entonces se comprende por que te avisa que *no existe*.

Con ello en mente entonces debería alcanzar con *completar* tu clase de este modo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers;

.......................
.......................    

class AuthController extends Controller
{
..................................
```

Comment: Al ingresar al link:  http://localhost:8000/login me arroja el siguiente error :  Target class [AuthController] does not exist.

Comment: Revisa que donde estés llamando a dicho controlador hayas realizado los cambios necesarios

Comment: Claro le agregue esta linea al controlador :  namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers;

Comment: Entonces considera editar tu pregunta con las adecuaciones hechas y el mensaje de error completo que obtienes